# Explain list comprehension in cumulative sum of list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

## Python code to get the Cumulative sum of a list

```
def Cumulative(lists): 
    cu_list = [] 
    length = len(lists) 
    cu_list = [sum(lists[0:x:1]) for x in range(0, length+1)] 
    return cu_list[1:] 

# Driver Code 
lists = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50] 
print (Cumulative(lists))
```

Can anyone help me to expand above list comprehension ?

I have written this code

```
def cum_sum(m):
    result = 0
    for x in m:
        result += x
        print(result, end=", ")


cum_sum([1,2,3,10])
```

Comment: Does https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/ help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expanded form of the list comprehension:

```
cu_list = []
for x in range(0, length+1):
    s = sum(lists[0:x:1])
    cu_list.append(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

use a generator

```
def cum_sum(m):
    result = 0
    for x in m:
        result += x
        yield result


list(cum_sum([1,2,3,10]))
```

Answer (score 1):

this part of your code

```
[sum(lists[0:x:1]) for x in range(0, length+1)]
```

creates a new list starting from the first element of `lists` up to (and excluding) the `x`'th element of your list (see e.g. [Python List Slicing](https://www.learnbyexample.org/python-list-slicing/)). then it takes the [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) over it.

so it unnecessarily creates several lists and does unnecessary sums (it could keep the sum up to element `x` in memory and just add the next element - as do most solutions presented here).

you get that for free with [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) already:

```
from itertools import accumulate


lists = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
print(list(accumulate(lists)))
# [10, 30, 60, 100, 150]
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
ans = []
for i in range(len(lists)):
    ans.append(sum(lists[:i+1]))
```